# Is it possible to determine if a method returns a Task and await it if it does?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

My goal is to pass any function with a return type to my Execute method and serialize and store its results.  Below is a rough idea of what I am trying to do, obviously won't compile but hopefully it gets the idea across.  I suppose I should also be able to handle nested Tasks recursively.  Thoughts?

```
public static TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<TResult> method)
        where TResult : class
    {

        var result = method();
        if(result is Task)
        {
            var taskResult = await result;
            StoreResult(taskResult);
        }
        else
        {
            StoreResult(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create two overloads, one which takes a `Func<Task<TResult>>` and the other a `Func<TResult>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Lee's comment that having a separate overload for `Func<Task<TResult>>` is the right solution.

But if you really want to do this using one overload, you could use reflection and `dynamic` to make this work:

```
public async static Task Execute<TResult>(Func<TResult> method) where TResult : class
{
    var result = method();

    if (typeof(TResult).IsGenericType
        && typeof(TResult).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
    {
        var taskResult = await (dynamic)result;
        StoreResult(taskResult);
    }
    else
    {
        StoreResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think I am going to do it with an overload but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a contrived example that shows how it can be done.

I'd question the wisdom of this pattern. I'd prefer to always return a task, even if a task isn't always needed. The overhead of `Task.FromResult()` is usually negligible.

```
public async Task<T> Foo<T>()
{
    var mightBeATask = Bar<T>();
    var task = mightBeATask as Task<T>;

    if( task != null )
    {
        return await task;
    }

    return (T)mightBeATask;
}

private object Bar<T>()
{
    return Task.FromResult( default( T ) );
}
```